# GREP Style Capital first letter

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

Is it possible to create a GREP function that will automatically change the first letter to capital letter in a word? For example: "moonlight" and GREP changes it to "Moonlight".
Don't want to use Find/replace, because I want to embedded in alinea style.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Like, every word in a story, or just specific words ?

Comment: Just a specific word. If i import text into Indesign, it would automatically change the word "moonlight" to "Moonlight". In that case, I don't have to worry about it

Answer (score 1):

In general you can't use styles in InDesign to change the *content* of a text - only the *appearance*.

But in this specific case, it *is* actually possible because uppercase can be styled.

Make a *Character Style* where you set *Basic Character Formats* to *All Caps*. You can call it "Uppercase" or something like that.

In the *Paragraph Style* where you want the substitution to take place, make a *GREP Style* like this:

[image]

This applies the style "Uppercase" to text which matches the pattern: `\<m(?=oonshine\>)`.

It selects an `m` in the beginning of a word `\<`, using a *Positive Lookahead* `(?=)` to make sure it's followed by `oonshine` which is the end of the word `\>`.

This seems to work well:

[image]

What might be a problem though, is that the character m isn't actually being substituted. It's just *styled*. So if you copy/paste the word from InDesign to another application, it won't be capitalized.

If you export a PDF and copy/paste from that, the word *will* be capitalized though. So it might not be a problem for you.

I wouldn't personally do it like this, as I think it obscures what's going on in your document. I would just perform a find/change at some point.

You could also look into using [Autocorrect](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/spell-checking-language-dictionaries.html), but it only works when typing the word letter by letter - not if you paste it in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.

You can use GREP Styles to change the formatting of a specific word, that includes applying a full uppercase formatting, but without an option to capitalize the first letter of a specific word.

As per the name, styles can only affect the formatting, not the content, in a story. Yes, you need a minor change, but I don't think that's what they made the styles for.